# R How to load Sparse data for arules package

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, arules

I have CSV which has text data that looks similar to:

```
citrus fruit,semi-finished bread,margarine,ready soups
tropical fruit,yogurt,coffee
whole milk
pip fruit,yogurt,cream cheese ,meat spreads
other vegetables,whole milk,condensed milk,long life bakery product
whole milk,butter,yogurt,rice,abrasive cleaner
```

I want to load this into sparse transaction form, what is the best way to do this?
i want to be able to use the arules package on it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `readLines`, then `strsplit` and then coerce to arules' `transactions` object

```
tran <- readLines("transactions.csv")      # read all lines
tran <- strsplit(tran, ",", fixed=TRUE)    # split each line by commas, returns a list

library(arules)
tran <- as(tran, Class =  "transactions")            # coerce to transaction object
rules <- apriori(tran, parameter=list(support=0.1))   # etc
inspect(rules[1])
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this when I've already got the data as a dataframe? I.e. i've done some preprocessing of the data and now want to coerce into a transaction object

Comment: It seems to split it into one list, I would like a list per row

Comment: Did you store it in _long format_ ? Like `data.frame(tran.id=c(1,1,2,2,2), item=c("citrus","fruit","yogurt","coffee","milk"))` ? If yes, see example in `?read.transactions` for `format="single"`

Comment: hello. No it is not in long format, it looks exactly how it does above, each new line is a new line

Comment: If you can provide the code used to process the file then we can see how to transform it into the format expected by arules.